# How can I make dropdown list with freemarker?

Tags: spring-mvc, jsp, freemarker

I am trying to get a list from datatbase using Freemarker. I want to make select dropdown list, but I don't undestand what I missed.

I did this:

```
<div class="form-group">
<select name="category" class="form-control" required>
    <#list categories! as category>
        <option value="${category.id}">${category.name}</option>
    </#list>
</select>
</div>
```

I have a form but I don't see any options.

With Thymeleaf I could do this but in the project I want to use freemarker

```
<div class="form-group">
    <select th:field="*{category}" class="form-control" required>
        <th:block th:each="category : ${categories}">
        <option th:text="${category.name}" value="${category.id}"/>
        </th:block>
    </select>
</div>
```

In fact I need "translate" this part from Thymeleaf to Freemarker and I don't know how.

Comment: Freemarker code is correct. Seek for other possible reasons. Maybe your backed is not working properly. Check page source (Chrome Ctrl+U) - maybe you've missed a closing tag or a parenthesis. Output some simple template - check if freemarker working at all.

Comment: Only thing I would question is exclamation mark on `categories!` - cause if categories is null, then you'll see a select without options which does not make sense. But this sould not be the reason for the whole thing to not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the code fragement was correct, I just placed in a PostMapping instead of GetMapping. Now it works good with controller below:

```
@GetMapping("/items")
public String main(Model model) {
    Iterable<Item> items;
    model.addAttribute("items", items);

    List<Category> categories = categoryRepository.findAll();
    model.addAttribute("categories", categories);

    return "items";
}
```